# Can application hosted in tomcat use "tomcat-vault"?

Tags: tomcat, hashicorp-vault, jboss-web

I am developing a Java web application that is hosted in Tomcat. Tomcat is actually part of Red Hat JBoss Web Server (JWS) 3.1. Admin team has decided to use "tomcat-vault" feature to store sensitive data/strings like passwords.

I would like to know if there is any way I can store and retrieve my application's sensitive data (like connection strings or certificate passwords) in that vault.

This seems to be pretty new feature and I could not find any mention of such a use case.